# Passing query parameters in a cross domain tracking setup

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have two websites which are configured for Cross Domain Tracking using Google Tag Manager. So at some point after the window load event, Google changes all the URLs that have to be cross domain tracked by appending a Client ID.
My question was however, how do we pass a query parameter from one domain to the other without breaking the cross domain tracking setup? For ex. coupon codes, etc.

Comment: Add it to the click url. The GA link decorator method adds the client id (rather the cross domain tracking id, which is mostly identical to the client id) only after the user has clicked the link and respects parameters that already exist.

Comment: when you say add it to the click url, do you mean something like `$('anchor tag identifier').attr('href',"http://www.website.com?promo=(get_promo_here)")`
The problem with this approach is, at times GA has already appended the cross domain tracking id, and at times it hasn't. I just want to know the safest way to change the anchor tag URLs. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you can do here is to setup a decorate link tag in gtm.

Here is how you can learn more about this
See Link / Form Decorate tag
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106951?rd=1

The other thing you can do here is that before appending your parameter check if your anchor already contain a parameter or not and append your parameter accordingly.

hope this helps,

Cheers Analytics ML